# implict declaration of function - vlc android

Tags: android, vlc, vlc-android

i want to compile the android version of vlc player but in progress i have two error as follow :

```
../../src/misc/block.c:315:5: error: implicit declaration of function 'shmdt' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

../../src/posix/filesystem.c:258:16: error: implicit declaration of function 'sigtimedwait' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

i searched many posts here or in another forums for **implicit** problem and they say it's because not importing lib / header file.

**shmdt** want `shm.h` and it is in `block.c` file correctly. and **sigtimedwait** have its own header.

i have this problem about two days and change many lines of code.
how can i fix this ? any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler wants to know the function before it can use it
just declare the function before you call it
You can add definition of method sigtimedwait in file filesystem.c.

That means add following:

int sigtimedwait(const sigset_t *set, siginfo_t *info,
                 const struct timespec *timeout);

See https://linux.die.net/man/2/sigtimedwait